# Remove Sveltekits A11y errors from [vite-plugin-svelte]

Tags: accessibility, sveltekit

Is this new in Sveltekit July 2023? I've used Sveltekit many times and I opened some old components in a new sveltekit project and I'm getting a lot of Aria Role errors. I know I can use !-- svelte-ignore a11y-no-static-element-interactions --> but that works for only one component page.
How can I disable all the errors popping up in my terminal? I don't agree with it, in general I simply don't want to follow the "rules".
Do I make changes in vite.config.js, or svelte.config.js?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's an onwarn flag you can use in svelte.config.js, according to the [vite-plugin-svelte docs](https://github.com/sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte/blob/main/docs/config.md#onwarn):

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    svelte({
      onwarn(warning, defaultHandler) {
        // don't warn on <marquee> elements, cos they're cool
        if (warning.code === 'a11y-distracting-elements') return;

        // handle all other warnings normally
        defaultHandler(warning);
      }
    })
  ]
});
```

That's the example from the docs, clearly you'd update the warning:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    svelte({
      onwarn(warning, defaultHandler) {
        if (warning.code === 'a11y-no-static-element-interactions') return;

        // handle all other warnings normally
        defaultHandler(warning);
      }
    })
  ]
});
```

Comment: Does not work though. Still get vscode yellow squiggly lines giving aria error.

`export default defineConfig({
 plugins: [
  sveltekit({
   onwarn(warning, defaultHandler) {
    if (warning.code === 'a11y-no-static-element-interactions') return;

    // handle all other warnings normally
    defaultHandler(warning);
   },
  }),
 ]`

Comment: you might try warning.message.includes("A11y"), works for me.

Comment: @comte do you mean if(warning.message.includes ("a11y") return;   and not warning.code as in the suggestions?  do you have a link to documentation?  There are so many different takes on this including bard/chatgpt.   They are all different.   Also my config has plutins: sveltekit, not svelte.